# telebot через proxy не работает

Tags: proxy, telebot

В общем проблема законнектица в телегу из-за роскомнадзора. Ниже два варианта proxy-коннекта через apihelper и манкипатчинг. Прокси сервер взят [отсюда](http://spys.one/proxys/US/): 198.199.120.102:1080 проверен через telnet коннект есть(комманда telnet 198.199.120.102 1080 не ругается, вылазит пустое cmd окно).
Вариант через apihelper:

```
import config
import telebot
from telebot import apihelper
import socks, socket

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.token)
apihelper.proxy = {'https':'socks5://198.199.120.102:1080'}
#socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, '80.248.225.58', '31431')

def sm():
    bot.send_message(config.chat_id, 'Привет')

bot.polling(none_stop=True)

sm()
```

Ругается так: `

```
C:\Python\q\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Python/q/send_mes.py
2020-06-07 23:46:58,413 (util.py:68 PollingThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "ConnectionError occurred, args=(MaxRetryError("SOCKSHTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /bot<мой токен>/getUpdates?offset=1&timeout=20 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.contrib.socks.SOCKSHTTPSConnection object at 0x02B42D50>: Failed to establish a new connection: Connection closed unexpectedly'))"),)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\socks.py", line 809, in connect
    negotiate(self, dest_addr, dest_port)
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\socks.py", line 444, in _negotiate_SOCKS5
    self, CONNECT, dest_addr)
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\socks.py", line 524, in _SOCKS5_request
    resp = self._readall(reader, 3)
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\socks.py", line 278, in _readall
    raise GeneralProxyError("Connection closed unexpectedly")
socks.GeneralProxyError: Connection closed unexpectedly

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\contrib\socks.py", line 81, in _new_conn
    **extra_kw
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\socks.py", line 209, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\socks.py", line 199, in create_connection
    sock.connect((remote_host, remote_port))
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\socks.py", line 47, in wrapper
    return function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\socks.py", line 814, in connect
    raise GeneralProxyError("Socket error", error)
socks.GeneralProxyError: Socket error: Connection closed unexpectedly

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 578, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 351, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 814, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 254, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\contrib\socks.py", line 103, in _new_conn
    "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % error
requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <requests.packages.urllib3.contrib.socks.SOCKSHTTPSConnection object at 0x02B42D50>: Failed to establish a new connection: Connection closed unexpectedly

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 403, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 623, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 281, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: SOCKSHTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /bot<мой токен>/getUpdates?offset=1&timeout=20 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.contrib.socks.SOCKSHTTPSConnection object at 0x02B42D50>: Failed to establish a new connection: Connection closed unexpectedly'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 62, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 281, in __retrieve_updates
    updates = self.get_updates(offset=(self.last_update_id + 1), timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 251, in get_updates
    json_updates = apihelper.get_updates(self.token, offset, limit, timeout, allowed_updates)
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 199, in get_updates
    return _make_request(token, method_url, params=payload)
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 63, in _make_request
    timeout=(connect_timeout, read_timeout), proxies=proxy)
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 475, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 585, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 467, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: SOCKSHTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /bot<мой токен>/getUpdates?offset=1&timeout=20 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.contrib.socks.SOCKSHTTPSConnection object at 0x02B42D50>: Failed to establish a new connection: Connection closed unexpectedly'))
"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\socks.py", line 809, in connect
    negotiate(self, dest_addr, dest_port)
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\socks.py", line 444, in _negotiate_SOCKS5
    self, CONNECT, dest_addr)
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\socks.py", line 524, in _SOCKS5_request
    resp = self._readall(reader, 3)
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\socks.py", line 278, in _readall
    raise GeneralProxyError("Connection closed unexpectedly")
socks.GeneralProxyError: Connection closed unexpectedly

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\contrib\socks.py", line 81, in _new_conn
    **extra_kw
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\socks.py", line 209, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\socks.py", line 199, in create_connection
    sock.connect((remote_host, remote_port))
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\socks.py", line 47, in wrapper
    return function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\socks.py", line 814, in connect
    raise GeneralProxyError("Socket error", error)
socks.GeneralProxyError: Socket error: Connection closed unexpectedly

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 578, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 351, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 814, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 254, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\contrib\socks.py", line 103, in _new_conn
    "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % error
requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <requests.packages.urllib3.contrib.socks.SOCKSHTTPSConnection object at 0x02B42D50>: Failed to establish a new connection: Connection closed unexpectedly

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 403, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 623, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 281, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: SOCKSHTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /bot<мой токен>/getUpdates?offset=1&timeout=20 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.contrib.socks.SOCKSHTTPSConnection object at 0x02B42D50>: Failed to establish a new connection: Connection closed unexpectedly'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python/q/send_mes.py", line 15, in <module>
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 415, in polling
    self.__threaded_polling(none_stop, interval, timeout)
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 438, in __threaded_polling
    polling_thread.raise_exceptions()
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 81, in raise_exceptions
    six.reraise(self.exc_info[0], self.exc_info[1], self.exc_info[2])
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 703, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 62, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 281, in __retrieve_updates
    updates = self.get_updates(offset=(self.last_update_id + 1), timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 251, in get_updates
    json_updates = apihelper.get_updates(self.token, offset, limit, timeout, allowed_updates)
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 199, in get_updates
    return _make_request(token, method_url, params=payload)
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 63, in _make_request
    timeout=(connect_timeout, read_timeout), proxies=proxy)
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 475, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 585, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 467, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: SOCKSHTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /bot<мой токен>/getUpdates?offset=1&timeout=20 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.contrib.socks.SOCKSHTTPSConnection object at 0x02B42D50>: Failed to establish a new connection: Connection closed unexpectedly'))

Process finished with exit code 1
```

`

Второй вариант через манкипатчинг:

```
import config
import telebot
import socket
import socks

ip = '198.199.120.102'  # change your proxy's ip
port = 1080  # change your proxy's port
socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, ip, port)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.token)

def sm():
    bot.send_message(config.chat_id, 'Привет')

bot.polling(none_stop=True)

sm()
```

Ругается так:

```
    C:\Python\q\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Python/q/test.py
2020-06-07 23:53:40,977 (util.py:68 PollingThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "ConnectionError occurred, args=(MaxRetryError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /bot<мой токен>/getUpdates?offset=1&timeout=20 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x02AE3BF0>: Failed to establish a new connection: Socket error: Connection closed unexpectedly'))"),)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\socks.py", line 809, in connect
    negotiate(self, dest_addr, dest_port)
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\socks.py", line 444, in _negotiate_SOCKS5
    self, CONNECT, dest_addr)
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\socks.py", line 524, in _SOCKS5_request
    resp = self._readall(reader, 3)
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\socks.py", line 278, in _readall
    raise GeneralProxyError("Connection closed unexpectedly")
socks.GeneralProxyError: Connection closed unexpectedly

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 142, in _new_conn
    (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 91, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 81, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\socks.py", line 47, in wrapper
    return function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\socks.py", line 814, in connect
    raise GeneralProxyError("Socket error", error)
socks.GeneralProxyError: Socket error: Connection closed unexpectedly

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 578, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 351, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 814, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 254, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 151, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x02AE3BF0>: Failed to establish a new connection: Socket error: Connection closed unexpectedly

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 403, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 623, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 281, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /bot<мой токен>/getUpdates?offset=1&timeout=20 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x02AE3BF0>: Failed to establish a new connection: Socket error: Connection closed unexpectedly'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 62, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 281, in __retrieve_updates
    updates = self.get_updates(offset=(self.last_update_id + 1), timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 251, in get_updates
    json_updates = apihelper.get_updates(self.token, offset, limit, timeout, allowed_updates)
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 199, in get_updates
    return _make_request(token, method_url, params=payload)
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 63, in _make_request
    timeout=(connect_timeout, read_timeout), proxies=proxy)
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 475, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 585, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 467, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /bot<мой токен>/getUpdates?offset=1&timeout=20 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x02AE3BF0>: Failed to establish a new connection: Socket error: Connection closed unexpectedly'))
"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\socks.py", line 809, in connect
    negotiate(self, dest_addr, dest_port)
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\socks.py", line 444, in _negotiate_SOCKS5
    self, CONNECT, dest_addr)
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\socks.py", line 524, in _SOCKS5_request
    resp = self._readall(reader, 3)
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\socks.py", line 278, in _readall
    raise GeneralProxyError("Connection closed unexpectedly")
socks.GeneralProxyError: Connection closed unexpectedly

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 142, in _new_conn
    (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 91, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 81, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\socks.py", line 47, in wrapper
    return function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\socks.py", line 814, in connect
    raise GeneralProxyError("Socket error", error)
socks.GeneralProxyError: Socket error: Connection closed unexpectedly

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 578, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 351, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 814, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 254, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 151, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x02AE3BF0>: Failed to establish a new connection: Socket error: Connection closed unexpectedly

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 403, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 623, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 281, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /bot<мой токен>/getUpdates?offset=1&timeout=20 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x02AE3BF0>: Failed to establish a new connection: Socket error: Connection closed unexpectedly'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python/q/test.py", line 16, in <module>
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 415, in polling
    self.__threaded_polling(none_stop, interval, timeout)
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 438, in __threaded_polling
    polling_thread.raise_exceptions()
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 81, in raise_exceptions
    six.reraise(self.exc_info[0], self.exc_info[1], self.exc_info[2])
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 703, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 62, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 281, in __retrieve_updates
    updates = self.get_updates(offset=(self.last_update_id + 1), timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 251, in get_updates
    json_updates = apihelper.get_updates(self.token, offset, limit, timeout, allowed_updates)
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 199, in get_updates
    return _make_request(token, method_url, params=payload)
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 63, in _make_request
    timeout=(connect_timeout, read_timeout), proxies=proxy)
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 475, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 585, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\q\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 467, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /bot<мой токен>/getUpdates?offset=1&timeout=20 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x02AE3BF0>: Failed to establish a new connection: Socket error: Connection closed unexpectedly'))

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Не до конца понимаю в каком месте должна стоять строчка bot.polling(none_stop=True) после или до вызова sm()

Версии питона и плагинов такие: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]